# Update column based on existing column and a condition in R

Tags: r

I am trying to mutate a column called Historic Penalty containing NA based on two columns, one with TRUE/FALSE named inspection count and other with a score named penalty.

```
    UPDATED_PENALTY['HISTORIC_PENALTY'] <- NA
 for (INSPECTION_CLEARED in TRUE) {
   mutate(HISTORIC_PENALTY = PENALTY*((0.8)^INSPECTION_COUNT))
   }
```

this is the code I am trying to run but I am getting the following error.

```
 Error in mutate(HISTORIC_PENALTY = PENALTY * ((0.8)^INSPECTION_COUNT)) : 
  object 'PENALTY' not found
```

Is there a better way of doing this or solving the error?

PENALTY column exist in my dataframe.

Comment: You may need `UPDATED_PENALTY <- mutate(UPDATED_PENALTY, HISTORIC_PENALTY = ..` if the data.frame name is `UPDATED_PENALTY`.  Also the `for` loop is not needed.  `if(INSPECTION_CLEARED) UPDATED_PENALTY <- mutate(UPDATED_PENALTY, HISTORIC_PENALTY = ..`

Comment: `for (INSPECTION_CLEARED in TRUE)` doesn't make sense... I'm not sure what you're trying to do there but you probably don't need a for loop.

Comment: @akrun I used your method but it is giving the following error Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `HISTORIC_PENALTY = PENALTY * ((0.8) * INSCPECTION_COUNT)`.
i The error occurred in group 1: OFFICIAL_NUMBER = "100768".
Caused by error in `mask$eval_all_mutate()`:
! object 'INSCPECTION_COUNT' not found
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: What is the error now

Comment: Do you have a column `INSPECTION_COUNT` or is the name `INSCPECTION_COUNT`

Comment: @akrun Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `HISTORIC_PENALTY = PENALTY * ((0.8) * INSCPECTION_COUNT)`.
i The error occurred in group 1: OFFICIAL_NUMBER = "100768".
Caused by error in `mask$eval_all_mutate()`:
! object 'INSCPECTION_COUNT' not found
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Please check the spelling of the column name `INSPECTION_COUNT` ?

Comment: @akrun it updated historic penalty for INSPECTION_CLEARED = FALSE too, I just need for TRUE any idea?

Comment: @AvneeshChaudhary i thought `INSPECTION_CLEARED <- TRUE` ?  Is it a column in the dataset?

Comment: Try the update in my post (if you have a column INSPECTION_CLEARED which is logical

Comment: @akrun yes it is a column, Thanks

Comment: Then, the update should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this helps

```
library(dplyr)
UPDATED_PENALTY <- UPDATED_PENALTY %>%
    mutate(
      HISTORIC_PENALTY = case_when(INSPECTION_CLEARED~ 
          PENALTY * ((0.8)^INSPECTION_COUNT), 
           TRUE ~ PENALTY))
```

---

In the OP's code, `mutate` was used without the dataframe object name